# Can I increase the size of menu buttons in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

So my Intellij install has buttons that, to me, are way too small. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

As you can see the buttons are tiny, is there an easy way to make them not so tiny?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the button size manually. If you're using IntelliJ IDEA on a high DPI display, IntelliJ IDEA version 15 (which is currently available as an Early Access Preview version) will automatically scale all UI elements according to the Windows scaling settings.

Comment: Thanks but that won't help me either, when I scale using the windows ones all the text blurs. An answer of "it isn't possible" is a valid answer :-). Is there any way I can do it from a more manual approach (I.E. replace images or something?)

Comment: Well, the code is open-source, so you can manually do anything you want. Replacing images is not sufficient, because the rest of the UI is laid out assuming the current size of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can just bear with it for now or if you are using IDEA Community, edit some code in there.